# jquery ajax not rendering html

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm returning some preformtatted data from the server as a string. this is passed to the ajax results. For some reason the html is just displayed as a string rather than links etc.

this is what I want

```
<a href='#'>test</a>
```

this is what i get

```
&lt;a href='#'&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;
```

This is my code

```
    function displayData(startRow, pageNumber) {
        // there's a call to jQuery AJAX here 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "default.aspx/GetPageLinks",
            data: "{startRow: '" + startRow + "', pageNumber: '" + pageNumber + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                displayRoutes(msg.d);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    });

    function displayRoutes(results) {
        $('#tradeRoutes').html(results);            
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you 100% sure you didn't already pass the response to the POST through an encoding stage at the server side?

Update: i.e. is the server returning a string with real angle brackets in, or is it returning a string full of `&lt;/&gt;` encoded angle brackets?

If it's the latter, then the problem is at the server, not at the browser, because you want to be sending real HTML, not HTML encoded as text.

I'd use something like Fiddler (or Wireshark, or Firebug) to check what the actual server response is.

Also put an alert() call in displayRoutes to see what 'results' is actually set to.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you didn't already pass the response to the POST through an encoding stage at the server side? I'm not entirely sure what you mean. sorry. I'm using asp.net HtmlTextWriter to create the html links etc?
Looking at the alert output it display the aforementioned encoded version of href.

Comment: @hoakey: Can you post the specific part of `GetPageLinks` that is returning the string representation of the link to the end of your question for us please?

Comment: @hoakey - I have tried to expand on that a bit.  I can't really tell from your comment what you're seeing with alert - to my mind, all the various possibilities were 'aforementioned'!

Comment: Here's an example of how the html is built server side -
HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell(); cell2.InnerText += "<a href='TradeRouteDetails.aspx?'>"

Comment: You should use InnerHtml, not InnerText

Comment: I did try that but it still rendered as a string. V odd.

Comment: @hoakey, you *must* establish if the problem is on the client or the server - if you don't have 'fiddler', http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ go and get it now.

Comment: I'm on it! I'm using codeSluth's replace suggestions as a temp fix which is doing the trick short term. But it'll be nice to see what fiddler2 uncovers. Many thanks. Stu.

Comment: It's the server that's encoding the angle brackets. Thanks for the fiddler recomendation. That's going to come in super useful in the future!

Comment: If you post the code (more than just the one line you already added to a comment) which generates the server-side response, we can help you work out why it's not working.  But in general, if you're setting properties called 'xxxText', they're going to be encoding the HTML into text, which is not what you want.

Comment: HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();    
                    HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();        
                    row.Cells.Add(cell2);
                    tbl.Rows.Add(row);
                    row = new HtmlTableRow();              
               tbl.RenderControl(tw);
            }
        }
        return sb.ToString();

Comment: Well, putting back in the cell2.InnerText bit you posted before, you get the encoded mistake in the middle of the table.  If you use InnerHtml, it works properly.   If you could bring yourself to post the full code, not random snippets, into an edit to your existing one, I'll see if there's anything else wrong.  But the InnerText is the main bug at the moment.

Comment: if I look at this
cell2.InnerHtml += string.Format("<a href='Trade_Routes/TradeRouteDetails.aspx?StartPostcode={0}&EndPostcode={1}'>", tradeRoute.StartPostCode, tradeRoute.EndPostCode) + tradeRoute.StartName;

in the vs text vizualizer it looks like this - 

&lt;a href='Trade_Routes/TradeRouteDetails.aspx?StartPostcode=de21 2ru&amp;EndPostcode=de1 3sf'&gt;derby - derby&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: public string GetDivElements(List<TradeRoutes> tradeRoutes)
{HtmlTable tbl = new HtmlTable();sb sb = new sb();using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
{using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw)){HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow()foreach (var tradeRoute in tradeRoutes)
{HtmlTableCell cell = new HtmlTableCell();cell.InnerText = tradeRoute.ConsignmentDate.ToString("dd-MM");
row.Cells.Add(cell);

Comment: HtmlTableCell cell2 = new HtmlTableCell();cell2.InnerHtml += string.Format("<a href='Trade_Routes/TradeRouteDetails.aspx?StartPostcode={0}&EndPostcode={1}'>", tradeRoute.StartPostCode, tradeRoute.EndPostCode) + tradeRoute.StartName;
 cell2.InnerText += " - ";cell2.InnerText += tradeRoute.EndName;cell2.InnerText += "</a>";row.Cells.Add(cell2);
HtmlTableCell cell3 = new HtmlTableCell();cell3.InnerText = (tradeRoute.AvailableSpace).ToString();
cell3.InnerText += " cft";row.Cells.Add(cell3);tbl.Rows.Add(row);row = new HtmlTableRow();}
tbl.RenderControl(tw);}}return sb.ToString();}

Comment: What are you looking at with the text visualizer - cell2.InnerHtml?

Comment: I can't really be bothered to read any more code in comments.  But you're still writing HTML in via InnerText, and I suspect that mixing all your += of InnerHtml and InnerText is doomed to fail anyway.   I would build-up the contents of the cell as HTML, using Html.Encode on the bits that were text, and then I would just assign it to InnerHtml.   Please don't post more code in comments - edit your original question if you want to add it.

Comment: Yes. Will, I'm concious that I'm taking up alot of your time with this. Your help so far has been invaluable, and has provided me with some great starting blocks to solve this. I'm more than happy that you've answered my question. I just need to do a little digging now. Cheers. Stu!

Comment: That was it! It was the combination of both innerHtml and innerText. Appologies for my profound stupidity. Thanks once again! A very happy Stu

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Will Dean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152758/jquery-ajax-not-rendering-html/4152826#4152826), try this:

```
function decodeHtml(encodedHtml) {
    return encodedHtml.replace(/&amp;/g,'&')
        .replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
}

function displayRoutes(results) {
    $('#tradeRoutes').html(decodeHtml(results));
}
```

This is from the jQuery plugin equivalent here: [jQuery plugin - HTML decode and encode](http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/10/21/jquery-plugin-html-decode-and-encode/)

At least this should get your code working while you figure out what's making it do it.